# log4j: ConversionPattern for ConsoleAppender is not working

Tags: java, log4j, consoleappender

I have log4j property (log4j v1.2.16) file where I have used both `RollingFileAppender` and `ConsoleAppender`.
configuration for `RollingFileAppender` as follows:

```
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${log.dir}\\mpnlog.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=400KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-6r[%20.20t] %-5p %45.45c %x - %m%n
```

configuration for `ConsoleAppender` as follows:

```
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %45.45c %x - %m%n
```

I am getting proper output with date time stamp in `RollingFileAppender` i.e. in mpnlog.log  but in **catalina.out** file I am not getting Date-time stamp for `System.out.println()`.. I dont know where exactly I am doing the mistake. I need proper date time stamp for Sysout statements in catalina.out file.

Anyone... know how to add date time stamp using above or any other approach to catalina.out ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the log level

Eg :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
```

Better change to log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">   
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %45.45c %x - %m%n/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

<root>
        <priority value="info"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: I already have `log4j.rootLogger=INFO, DEBUG,console,R` at the top, I didn't mention this in question.